# Obtaining Added Item Information with vsx

Tags: events, event-handling, vsx, subtype

I just created an event handler to determine when a new item is added to the solution explorer; however, I'm unable to obtain the properties of the item(Name, etc).

In the event handler method, I just have my project item.  Is there any way I could possibly use an interface to obtain the information I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following articles from Carlos Quintero explain in detail about how to subscribe and get information from the ProjectEvents.

[HOWTO: Initializing new events in Visual Studio macros](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007019.aspx)

[HOWTO: Getting Project and ProjectItem events from a Visual Studio .NET add-in.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/mz2005009.aspx)